# Highly upvoted questions should count longer as unanswered than lowly voted questions

Tags: feature-request

If a lot of people view a question with multiple answers it's likely that one of the answers gets a vote even if it isn't that fully answering the question. When a lot of people upvote the question one can also assume that they are interested in a detailed answer.

Therefore I propose that once a question has three votes it needs an accepted answer or an answer with two votes to be seen as answered.

When it reaches five votes it needs an accepted answer or an answer with three votes to be seen as answered.

When it reaches ten votes it needs an accepted answer or an answer with four votes to be seen as answered.